# send form data to API by curl

Tags: php, html, curl

I would like to send a form data to API  this API has a key and profile must be provided then after sending data by post request i have to send get request to get the info back

this is the post function they provide :

```
curl -k -X POST --header "X-API-KEY:TOKEN" -F "profile=B2B" -F
"data_file=@/var/tmp/testfile.csv" -F "md5=ae0eca4f5671cbdc19340a1df2567611"
https://api.cloudHygiene.com/task/run
```

and this is the get function they provide :

```
curl -k -X GET --header "X-API-KEY:TOKEN"
https://api.cloudhygiene.com/task/get_file? 
package_name=hWviW2hLui_1477652942&f
ilename=_report.xls
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? It looks like you have all of the information necessary to use cURL within PHP to accomplish your task.

Comment: actually i don't know how to use this info :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to run the cURL command in PHP? If so here is the first part of the cURL request in PHP:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cloudHygiene.com/task/run");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Api-Key: TOKEN";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Here is the second part:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cloudhygiene.com/task/get_file?");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Api-Key: TOKEN";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Again, I am only speculating you are asking to run the cURL request in PHP. If not, I suggest rewording your question and providing more details.

Comment: thanx alot  how can i link this code to the html form ?